Formaldehyde in SEAr with deactivated ring, and reactivity of bromoacetic acid in substitution reaction?
About this paper:
https://doi.org/10.1021/la0000623
They reacted PET with 18.5 % formaldehyde and 1M acetic acid in a nucelophilic substitution to produce a primary alcohol on the aromatic ring, which was then coupled with 1 M bromoacetic acid under 2 M NaOH to have a -COOH functionality for amide coupling.

Terephthalic acid is a deactivated system. I could not replicate this reaction. Do you think its plausible?
How does the bromoacetic acid react with the primary alcohol with double the amount of NaOH? 1 M of NaoH is directly neutralized by bromoacetic acid. Doesn´t the hydroxide already eliminate the bromide? why is the coupling to the alcohol preferred?

so I already assumed that these were false positive findings, because hydrolysis of polymer chain would produce same effects.
In the paper they even say then:
"We believe that the low MW PET oligomers are created by hydrolytic chain cleavage of PET, which also creates hydroxyl and carboxylic acid groups at the new chain ends. Therefore, the scheme shown in Figure 1 is only approximate, and it is likely that a substantial fraction of reactive groups arise from side reactions such as hydrolytic cleavage of the PET backbone."
Interestingely they still seem to think it works at least for some part or why tf would one give this scheme then? But i guess it wasnt´t plausible from the start.

Well, you mention things than may not work and why, but these sound like stuff possible to overcome.

what do you mean? I just wanna know if these reactions are expected and why the second one works like that?
